# Better way to implement a behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, behavior

I'm relatively new to WPF and Behaviors.

I have this behavior, I need to execute DoSomething() every time I set IsRedundant in the ViewModel.

Each time I need to trigger DoSomething, I would need to change the value of the property and this is confusing (if ture => set it to false, If false => set it to true). IsRedundant only used to raise the property changed event and for nothing else.

Is there a better way of achieving this ?

Any ideas ?

## wpf

```
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:UIElementBehavior  Redundant="{Binding IsRedundant, Mode=TwoWay}"/ >
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

## C#

```
class UIElementBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RedundantProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Redundant",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(UIElementBehavior),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, DoSomething));

        public bool Redundant
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(RedundantProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RedundantProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void DoSomething(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something on the AssociatedObject
        }

    }
```

Comment: _"there must be a better way of achieving this"_ define "better" ...

Comment: @Fildor I might be using the wrong idea  to achieve this. I'm only using IsRedundant to trigger DoSomething().

Comment: But we don't know what DoSomething is, and how it relates to IsRedundant, so it's hard to answer. Does it set a property of the UIElement? If so, data triggers might be simpler. But it's hard to say without more information.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I made this question general. However, DoSomething is doing some complicated customization like theme changes on customized data grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each time I need to trigger DoSomething, I would need to change the value of the property and this is confusing (if true => set it to false, If false => set it to true)

The problem is that you are using binding. Binding required target to be dependency property. And those are special, their setters aren't called, so you have to use callback to get informed when their value is changed via binding.

Moreover there is internally a check if value is different, for performance reasons callback is not called if value is the same, so you **must** change it as you do already.

---

An alternative solution is to simply add event in the view model:

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public EventHandler SomethingHappens;
     // call this to tell something to listener if any (can be view or another view model)
     public OnSomethingHappens() => SomethingHappens?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

     ...
}
```

Now you can subscribe/unsubscribe in the view to/from this event and do something in the event handler. If you are purist, then refactor code from the view into reusable behavior.

Is it shorter? Nope. Is it more clear? Yes, compared to using `bool` and such *"wonderful"* code:

```
IsRedundant = false;
IsRedundant = true; // lol
```

---

I was using `bool` properties like you do to inform the view in the past.

Then I used events.

Now I use combination of both. Every view model already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so why not use it?

Think about `IsRedundant` as a *state*. It can be used not only to trigger some method, but also used by the view to run animations via data triggers, control visibility of dynamic layout, etc. So you need a normal `bool` property in view model.

The view then can subscribe to/unsubscribe from `PropertyChanged` and simply have to check:

```
if(e.PropertyName == nameof(ViewModel.IsRedudant)) { ... }
```